# What to do about the [erb] tag for Ruby?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-wiki

[erb](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/erb) was mentioned as [a possible rogue tag](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3673/do-we-have-some-rebel-tags-that-shouldnt-exist-on-code-review). It has currently has 3 questions and no wiki. It turns out that [`erb` is a Ruby class](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.4/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html). As best I can tell, [erb](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/erb) is used for [meta-programming](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta-programming).

Now, I see this tag as a problem because [we don't want language specific tags for concepts](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2075/41243). However, this assumes that I've interpreted what this class **is** correctly.

The way I see it, we have several options.

1. Add a tag wiki and leave it alone.
2. Re-tag it with an appropriate concept tag.
3. Simply burn it.

I could really use a domain expert's input on this. (It would be really great if a domain expert could add a wiki, at least until we decide what to do with the tag.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see those questions are about [ERB templating](http://www.stuartellis.eu/articles/erb/).

A combination of text with `<%  %> <%=  %> <%  -%> <%#  %>` and Ruby inside those delimiters.

This is a far cry from `NSString` and I think the erb tag should be left alone.
Of course, I am in the TPL<sup>*</sup>, so I am hardly objective ;)

<sup>*</sup> Tag Proliferation League

Comment: I'm 100% okay with that. It seems unique enough to warrant a tag to me. Would you mind creating a wiki for it though?

Comment: The deed is done

Comment: Muchos gracías Señor.